# Replacing Multiple Strings without Multiple SUBSTITUTE Formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have Sheet A with a list of "tokens" in Column A and the values of each token in Column B. There are over 100 different tokens.

```
| TOKEN    | VALUE             |
| -------  | ----------------- |
| [NAME]   | Michael           |
| [PHONE]  | (800) 555-1234    |
| [EMAIL]  | michael@gmail.com |
```

Then in Sheet B I have content that will use these different tokens.

```
| TITLE                     | DESCRIPTION                       |
| ------------------------  | --------------------------------- |
| Hello, my name is [NAME]  | This is a description for [NAME]  |
| Call me at [PHONE]        | This is a description for [PHONE] |
| Email me at[EMAIL]        | This is a description for [EMAIL] |
```

The tokens used in the content in Sheet B need to be replaced with the corresponding token values from Sheet A. My question is, how can I use a formula to look for and substitute these tokens in Sheet B with the token values in Sheet A without using 100 SUBSTITUTE formulas?

Here is an example with desired outcomes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jbZOe_MILqRLw-rUJwu9RKCM-c8GFX0jyWT3ByIVXy0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Added an example above

Comment: Please post a link to an editable spreadsheet with link permission set (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor." The link you've posted is not editable; so the volunteer contributors here have no way to access the data, review the data types, test formulas or leave formulas.

Comment: I can't find a formula ... I propose you a script to do it globally.

Comment: This can be accomplished with a single formula. But I am waiting for the OP, Travis, to share a spreadsheet per my previous comment.

Comment: I am also waiting for your response as I am interested in how to do this! Thx Erik

Comment: may be 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zeFgcgCwh87UIDdqFQO3NM_6ixxDHUFPRERp4lx05hE/edit

Comment: The problem I have, Mike, is that what is shown in the post doesn't match what is shown in the shared document. I am unclear as to whether *both* "TITLE" and "DESCRIPTION" data will appear in the real sheet or whether "DESCRIPTION" is only for explanatory purposes in the post (which seems superfluous). Knowing this would change how I approached formula writing. I'm also of a mind that poster's should be attending to their posts more than the volunteer contributors like you and me; so I'm going to wait until this poster responds with clarification.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, if you are personally interested in how I'd approach this with a formula, feel free to click on my name link and contact me via my website; I'm happy to share my idea with you directly. As far as here on the forum, however, as I say, I'll wait until when and if the OP responds, both for the sake of clarification on his post and on principle.

Comment: @ErikTyler Apologies for the delay. I was traveling the last few days. I've updated the link and made the sheet editable to anyone with the link.

Comment: Travis, see my newly added post below. @MikeSteelson, I added this solution to your shared sheetmaker sheet as well, for your own use.

Comment: Many thx Erik! Obviously, I ill not be able to find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a new sheet ("CONVERTED [Erik Help]"). The formula in A1 of that sheet produces the header and all results.

There are special considerations in a situation like this. For instance, a zip code and a date each consist of five numeric characters in memory (i.e., the zip code is obvious but dates are saved as the number of elapsed days since an origin date of December 30, 1899). So the formula needs to be able to distinguish the two, or dates would come through in the underlying five-digit form.

The solution involves "exploding" the original string into pieces. But some of those pieces are punctuation, which are tricky and must also be accounted for both in the "explode" and in the rejoin.

The formula was written to accommodate the Col-A data presently shown in TOKENS!A:A. If changes or additions are made to that data, the formula should still work as written, but it may produce unexpected results requiring modifications to the formula. (There is no way to account for future data that may not be of-a-kind with the data shown.)

Finally, I have to put out there that this solution goes beyond what can typically be offered via a free, volunteer-run forum. Forums are designed to share a little knowledge, a "nudge in the right direction" or small formula/script help with someone who has already worked out the underlying formula/script mostly correctly themselves. Obviously free forums cannot provide customized, time-intensive, expert-level solutions at no cost as a norm. So this formula is an exception to the rule (at least my rule). As such, while smaller formulas shared on this forum are generally explained as to how they work, I'm sharing this formula as-is and without explanation, since explaining would take longer than having written it.

The formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"FILLED";FILTER(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(CONTENT!A2:A,"\]\[","] ["),"([\s\.,\?\!\/\-\&"&CHAR(34)&"])","~$1")),"~",1)),{TOKENS!A:A,IF(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(TOKENS!A:A),"DATE"),TEXT(TOKENS!B:B,"mmm d, yyyy"),TOKENS!B:B)},2,FALSE),SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(CONTENT!A2:A,"\]\[","] ["),"([\s\.,\?\!\/\-\&"&CHAR(34)&"])","~$1")),"~",1))),,COLUMNS(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(CONTENT!A2:A,"\]\[","] ["),"([\s\.,\?\!\/\-\&"&CHAR(34)&"])","~$1")),"~",1))))),"\s([\.,\?\!\/\-\&"&CHAR(34)&"])","$1"),CONTENT!A2:A<>"")})`

Answer (score 0):

Try with script

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var dictionary = new Map()
  ss.getSheetByName('TOKENS').getDataRange().getDisplayValues().slice(1).forEach(x => dictionary.set(x[0], x[1]))
  var range = ss.getSheetByName('CONTENT').getRange(2, 1, ss.getSheetByName('CONTENT').getLastRow() - 1, 1)
  var data = range.getValues()
  data.forEach(function (row) {
    [...row[0].matchAll(/\[[\s\S\w]+?\]/g)].flat().forEach(t => row[0] = (dictionary.has(t)) ? row[0].replace(t, dictionary.get(t)) : row[0])
  })
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(data)
};
```

References:

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

[matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)